# Is there a way to get the index of an object in an array stored in firestore?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Ionic and firebase firestore. I want to be able to click a certain `ion-card` containing an object and call a method that would pop up an `ion-action-sheet` containing a **Delete** button where I can delete the particular object. This object is stored in an array in firestore.

This is how the data structure looks like:

[image: Firestore data structure]

This is my current HTML file for the `ion-card`

```html
<ion-card class="lightCard" *ngFor="let reviews of revArr" (click)="selectReview()">

        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-icon name="person-circle-sharp" class="profIcon"></ion-icon>
              <!-- <ion-card-subtitle>Card Subtitle</ion-card-subtitle> -->
              <ion-card-title class="cardUsername fontWhite" style="font-size: 35px;">{{reviews.userName}}</ion-card-title>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-grid>
          
        </ion-card-header>
          
        <ion-card-content class="font cardContent">
          <h1 class="title" style="font-weight: bold;">{{reviews.title}}</h1>
          {{reviews.review}}
        </ion-card-content>
      
      </ion-card>
```

And this the code inside the class:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    const compId: string = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); //get id

     //for reviews array in `reviews`
    this.reviewCollection = this.afStore.doc(`reviews/${compId}`)
    this.rev = this.reviewCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(item =>{
    this.revArr = item.reviews
    this.userNrev = item.reviews.userName
     })   
  }

  async selectReview(){
  
    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      header: "Delete "+ this.userNrev + "'s review?",
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Delete',
          handler: () => {
           //delete code
          }
        }
      ]
    })
    await actionSheet.present();
  }
```

The real question would be: how can I get the index from the array in firestore and use that index to delete the object?

It would be very nice if someone can help me, I am still very new at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firebase does not recommend using arrays** for that because it's easy to corrupt data when multiple people update the array at the same time.

You also should consider that a firebase **document has a max size of 1mb**. So if you have a lot of long reviews, you will reach that limit and also always load that huge file.

In your case you probably would need to alter the array in your code and update the whole field.

A **better solution** would be a **subcollection**, where every review is a document. Then fetching maybe 25 at a time (with limit())

Now you could update/delete every review very easy.

[Here is a Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ) to the official YouTube-Series where they explain Firestore and how to structure it.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I'll make use of the subcollections

Comment: "Firebase does not recommend using arrays" is overly simplistic advice for Firestore.  Arrays have a specific purpose, and several APIs for manipulation and querying. And transactions help code modify arrays without contention. They have a purpose, but they aren't a solution to all problems.

Comment: @DougStevenson thats true and I use arrays too in Firestore. I meant it's not recommended for that usecase.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is actually wrong for what you want to achieve:

- if you want to just store some random list of data, you can totally use an array inside a single document and put whatever data you want inside.
- but, as soon as you want to store data that you want to manipulate later (delete, update ...), you will have to store every entry in it's own document, one review -> one document. This will make it easier and more reliable to update or delete single reviews or even groups of reviews.

You can watch this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35RlydUf6xo&t=3s) if you are interested in using Firestore the correct way, Angular was used in it, so I think it's gonna help you go further.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am going to make use of subcollections for the reviews so i can have one review for one document as you mentioned